# I don't know how to access UpdateHeight(); for react-swipeable-routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The dashboard loads and the problem I have to swipe away and swipe back to update the height. So I am trying to pass it as props and useEffect to update the height. I just can't seem to understand what is going on.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard/Dashboard";
import Notifications from "./components/dashboard/Notifications";
import Profile from "./components/profile/Profile";
import SignIn from "./components/auth/SignIn";
import SignUp from "./components/auth/SignUp";
import './App.css';
import SwipeableRoutes from "react-swipeable-routes";
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';

const App = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    props.swipeableViews.UpdateHeight();
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />

      <SwipeableRoutes animateHeight>
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />

        <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/notifications" component={Notifications} />
        <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      </SwipeableRoutes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends helped me.
The problem was easy.

```
// Declare ref
var updateh = React.useRef();


<SwipeableRoutes
  animateHeight={true}
  // Accroding to the doc, you should just calla hook function called "action" and assign it to the ref to be able to call the callback functions inside it.
  action={(hooks) => {
    updateh.current = hooks;
  }}
>
  <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
  <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Dashboard updateh={updateh} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/notifications" component={Notifications} />
  <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
</SwipeableRoutes>
```